# Pandas conditionally copying of cell value

Tags: python, pandas

Working with a Pandas DataFrame, I am trying to copy data from one cell into another cell only if the recipient cell contains a specific value. The transfer should go from:

```
   Col1    Col2
0     4       X
1     2       5
2     1       X
3     7       8
4    12      20
5     3       X
```

And the result should be

```
   Col1    Col2
0     4       4
1     2       5
2     1       1
3     7       8
4    12      20
5     3       3
```

Is there an elegant or simple solution I am missing?

Comment: you can do mask = df['col2'] == 'x', then df.loc[mask, 'col2'] = df.loc[mask, 'col1']

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df.Col2 = df.Col1.where(df.Col2 == 'X', df.Col2)
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, since importing another module just slows everything down. Thanks!

Comment: @milleractual: I assume you're referring to the other answer here which does `import numpy as np`.  That won't slow anything down because Pandas already imports NumPy.  But anyway the two solutions are about the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.Col2 = np.where(df.Col2 == 'specific value', df.Col1, df.Col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pandas.DataFrame.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
>>> df.replace('X', np.nan, inplace=True)
>>> df.ffill(axis=1)
  Col1 Col2
0    4    4
1    2    5
2    1    1
3    7    8
4   12   20
5    3    3
```